# String.Split splitting on incorrect character

Tags: vb.net, string

In VB.NET 2010

Calling `string.split("³")` on this line `"³4002³1³1ÄTest³1ÄPhysician³"`

returns an array of 8 strings:

```
"","4002","1","1","Test","1","Physician",""
```

As far as I can tell `"³" != "Ä"`

This doesn't make any sense to me. Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening and maybe know how I can get it to give me the result I would expect?

Comment: I am not sure about vb.. but please verify your encoding that is being utilized by your regex parser and the character set you are feeding it

Comment: Splits correctly in C# so would seem to be an encoding issue.

Comment: Split correctly for me in a new VB.Net console app (VS 2010)

Comment: Yep, splits correctly for me too so this must be related to something else. Even tried on .NET framework 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

On VB.NET it may be attempting to convert the string into an encoding where neither the character ³, nor the character Ä can be interpreted correctly. They must be getting converted to a recognized 'default' best interpreted value, and those converted values would be returning true on the criteria for the .Split method.

Forcing unicode encoding on all strings *should* fix the problem (including encoding the .Split("³"). Encode it and save it to a variable before the split to be .Split(encodedValue)